# Jhipster / md-button is not a known element

Tags: material-design, angular-material, jhipster, angular-material2

Hello I am using JHipster 4.0.1

I want integrate angular 2 material into my home.component.

I did : 
        npm install material
        npm install angular2/{core,button}

```
 <html><head></head>
<body> 
<md-button>Hello </md-button></body></html>
```

the error is : md-button is not a known element

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For those using yarn rather than npm:

```
yarn add --exact @angular/material
yarn start
```

Import angular material module into `src/main/webapp/app/shared/shared-libs.module.ts`:

```ts
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MaterialModule,
        ...        ],
    exports: [
        MaterialModule,
        ...
```

Add a theme into `src/main/webapp/content/css/vendor.css`:

```css
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Add some MD elements to `src/main/webapp/app/home.component.html`:

```html
    <md-card>
        <button md-button class="mat-primary">Hello </button>
    </md-card>
```

Comment: md-card works but when i put md-button or other element it doesn't work!!

Comment: all directives working only <md-dutton> doesn't work

Comment: Did you notice that I used <button md-button> and not <md-button> ?

Comment: yes but as i am Beginner in material design i want to know why <md-button/>  doesn't work . i am sorry .

Comment: Because it is not supposed to be used like that, check the docs, it's an attribute not an element:   https://material.angular.io/components/component/button. I helped you and you did not accept my answer, this is not how stackoverflow works

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Keep in mind that just because StackOverflow allows you to submit questions doesn't always mean that the user has to accept that answer regardless of whether you think it's correct or not. Telling OP that "this is not how stackoverflow works" isn't the recommended way of handling it. Just my two cents.

Comment: @fuzz so what is your recommended way without knowing the context?