# How can I customize my jhipster gateway UI and use angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, jhipster, angular-material2

I am using jhipster microservice architecture for my project.
but i want to customize the UI.
and use material design with [material angular](https://material.angular.io/) framework.

I am using angular 4 in my project. 
I serarched a lot but I could not find any way for angular 4 .

How can I change my UI framework from bootstrap to material angular?

I'll be appreciated if anybody could help.

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall Bootstrap and [install](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) Angular Material.

Comment: Bootstrap Material Design module will not work as it  has not been updated for 2 years and so does not support angular 4.

Comment: ok I hear you, I will update my answer, thanks. For the sake of future readers, I completely deleted the reference to Bootstrap Material Design

Comment: can you please explain how can I uninstall Bootstrap?

and I use this [link](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) for installing angular material. is that enough or sth more is needed for making it work with jhipster?

Comment: Yes, this is the right link. What version of JHipster are you using? I took a look at [this](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app) and saw that it uses Bower to handle Bootstrap. Before getting you too much confused, can you focus first on installing and successfully use Angular?

Technically you don't even need to uninstall Bootstrap, you could simply not use it.

Comment: He is using angular 4 not angular 1 so no bower, an example of a generated jhipster app in angular 4 is [here](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-ng2) Additional hints specific to JHipster and material: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157853/jhipster-md-button-is-not-a-known-element

Comment: Ty that was the missing piece! So according to Gael Marziou 's link, the only two packages you need to uninstall are `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` and `bootstrap`. But first, try to install Angular material correctly